# Javascript's object.onClick runs the function instead of setting onClick, how can I prevent that from happening and only execute the function onClick?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, setattribute

I have the following code:

```
function sdefaults()
{
   alert("test");
}

var btnpos, sbtn;
btnpos = document.getElementsByName('somePosition')[0];
sbtn = document.createElement('input');
btnpos.parentNode.insertBefore(sbtn, btnpos.nextSibling);
sbtn.type = "button";
sbtn.name = "social";
sbtn.value = "Defaults";
sbtn.onClick = sdefaults();
```

The button appears where I want it to and the name/value are set correctly.  However when I load the page, the `sdefaults()` function is run and then if I click the button, nothing happens.  Could anyone provide any insight into how to prevent the function from running on load and force it to only run onclick?

Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis: Thanks for cleaning up his post. I would have if I could.

Answer (score 8):

Change:

```
sbtn.onClick = sdefaults();
```

to:

```
sbtn.onClick = sdefaults;
```

---

`sbtn.onClick = sdefaults();` means: "Run the `sdefaults` function and store the result in `sbtn.onClick`.

`btn.onClick = sdefaults;` means: "Set `sbtn.onClick` to the function `sdefaults`", which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I try that and it stops the function from running on page load, however clicking the button continues to do nothing.

Comment: @cd: try `onclick` instead of `onClick`?

Comment: Thanks for the response Josh.  onclick exhibits the same behaviour.

btn.onclick = sdefaults;

Comment: Then my recommendation would be to use a framework like jQuery or Prototype. I know this can be done easily in Prototype with `$(btn).observe('click',sdefaults);` -- I haven't actually used `btn.onclick` in years.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Josh.  because this is a greasemonkey script I don't think I can use Prototype.

Cheers

Comment: @cd, for what it's worth, you definitely can use jQuery with Greasemonkey, either by using `@require` or by inserting the `<script>` element into the page itself (e.g. http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/).

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand the difference between function referencing, and function invocation.

Consider the following function

```
function foo()
{
  alert( 'Hello World' );
}
```

Now, lets look at some samples of referencing this function.  To reference a function, we use its symbol name, just like any other variable.

```
// Alert contents of foo
alert( foo );

// Set foo as the click handler for the body
document.body.onclick = foo;

// Assign a new function to foo
foo = function(){ alert( 'Goodbye!' ); }
```

Now we'll consider function invocation.  This means the function executes and its return value is sent back to the calling scope.

```
// Invoke foo simply
foo();

// Invoke foo with a specific scope
foo.apply( this ); // or foo.call( this );
```

Now, it's entirely possible to modify your code snippet just by changing the code of `sdefaults()`.  Here's how that would look.

```
function sdefaults()
{
  return function()
  {
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

Now, when you execute `sbtn.onClick = sdefaults();` what happens is the `onClick` property receives what its expecting, a function, since we've modified sdefaults to not actually alert "test", but to return an anonymous function which itself will alert "test".  *(As a side note, this specific technique is commonly called a lambda or delegate function)*

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation... except you never told him to change his code to `btn.onClick = sdefaults;` which ultimately fixes the issue he's having... Instead you told him how to make `btn.onClick = sdefaults();` work, which is a little backwards in my opinion...

Comment: Well, I felt I didn't need to since your answer already does that.

Comment: Fair enough. Your answer was much more in depth than mine. I'll give you +1 tomorrow, I'm at my vote limit for the day :-)